# How can I implement sorting and filtering with RTK Query in my bug tracker PERN app using Redux Toolkit and createEntityAdapter API?

Tags: sorting, redux, filtering, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm currently developing a bug tracker PERN app. I'm using [**Redux Toolkit**](https://redux.js.org/) to manage global state and [**RTK Query**](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/queries) to fetch and cache data. I also normalized state with the aid of the **createEntityAdapter** API.

So far my app is working but I feel it's incomplete without some filter and sort features. This is where I'm stuck currently, specifically with trying to sort or filter using the **useQuery** hook. I binged on a [**RTK tutorial**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NqzdVN2tyvQ) by Dave Gray, which has helped me tons, I went through the [**Redux**](https://redux.js.org/) docs, I've googled many times about sorting and filtering with [**RTK Query**](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/queries), but I have not been able to solve it.

My objective is to sort and/or filter the current state based on a set of parameters that exist in the database (priority, severity, nature, application, user role, status). What I've tried so far is:

- Created a custom selector where I pass the parameter by which I want to sort. See **selectSortedTickets** at the bottom of my ***ticketsApiSlice.js*** below:

```
import { createSelector, createEntityAdapter } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { apiSlice } from "../../app/api/apiSlice";

const ticketsAdapter = createEntityAdapter({
  // sortComparer: (a, b) => (a.status === b.status ? 0 : a.status ? 1 : -1),
});

const initialState = ticketsAdapter.getInitialState();

export const ticketsApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getTickets: builder.query({
      query: () => ({
        url: "/tickets",
        validateStatus: (response, result) => {
          return response.status === 200 && !result.isError;
        },
      }),
      /* keepUnusedDataFor: 5,*/
      transformResponse: (responseData) => {
        return ticketsAdapter.setAll(initialState, responseData);
      },
      providesTags: (result, error, arg) => {
        if (result?.ids) {
          return [
            { type: "Ticket", id: "LIST" },
            ...result.ids.map((id) => ({ type: "Ticket", id })),
          ];
        } else return [{ type: "Ticket", id: "LIST" }];
      },
    }),
    addNewTicket: builder.mutation({
      query: (initialTicket) => ({
        url: "/tickets",
        method: "POST",
        body: {
          ...initialTicket,
        },
      }),
      invalidatesTags: [{ type: "Ticket", id: "LIST" }],
    }),
    updateTicket: builder.mutation({
      query: (initialTicket) => ({
        url: "/tickets",
        method: "PUT",
        body: {
          ...initialTicket,
        },
      }),
      invalidatesTags: (result, error, arg) => [{ type: "Ticket", id: arg.id }],
    }),
    deleteTicket: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ id }) => ({
        url: `/tickets`,
        method: "DELETE",
        body: { id },
      }),
      invalidatesTags: (result, error, arg) => [{ type: "Ticket", id: arg.id }],
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useGetTicketsQuery,
  useAddNewTicketMutation,
  useUpdateTicketMutation,
  useDeleteTicketMutation,
} = ticketsApiSlice;

// returns the query result object
export const selectTicketsResult =
  ticketsApiSlice.endpoints.getTickets.select();

// creates memoized selector
const selectTicketsData = createSelector(
  selectTicketsResult,
  (ticketsResult) => ticketsResult.data // normalized state object with ids & entities
);

//getSelectors creates these selectors and we rename them with aliases using destructuring
export const {
  selectAll: selectAllTickets,
  selectById: selectTicketById,
  selectIds: selectTicketIds,
  // Pass in a selector that returns the tickets slice of state
} = ticketsAdapter.getSelectors(
  (state) => selectTicketsData(state) ?? initialState
);

export const selectTicketsByUser = createSelector(
  [selectAllTickets, (state, userId) => userId],
  (tickets, userId) => tickets.filter((ticket) => ticket.userId === userId)
);

export const selectSortedTickets = createSelector(
  [selectAllTickets, (state, sortArg) => sortArg],
  (tickets, sortArg) => {
    if (sortArg === "Priority") {
      tickets.sort((a, b) => b.priority - a.priority);
    } else if (sortArg === "Severity") {
      tickets.sort((a, b) => b.severity - a.severity);
    } else if (sortArg === "Application") {
      tickets.sort((a, b) => {
        const nameA = a.application.toUpperCase();
        const nameB = b.application.toUpperCase();
        if (nameA < nameB) return -1;
        if (nameA > nameB) return 1;
        return 0;
      });
    } else if (sortArg === "Nature") {
      tickets.sort((a, b) => {
        const nameA = a.nature.toUpperCase();
        const nameB = b.nature.toUpperCase();
        if (nameA < nameB) return -1;
        if (nameA > nameB) return 1;
        return 0;
      });
    } else if (sortArg === "Assignee") {
      tickets.sort((a, b) => b.userId - a.userId);
    } else {
      tickets.sort((a, b) => b.status - a.status);
    }
  }
);
```

- Tried to sort the **useGetTicketsQuery** but I get an array with each *id* with its corresponding entity. I can't seem to reach the *entities* in order to sort them as I please.
- Thought of solving it in the backend with different endpoints and using different paths but it does not seem efficient.

The feature where I want to apply the sort is in this **SingleUserTicketsList.js** file:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useGetUsersQuery } from "../users/usersApiSlice";
import { useGetTicketsQuery } from "./ticketsApiSlice";
import PulseLoader from "react-spinners/PulseLoader";
import { priorityName } from "../../config/priority";
import { severityName } from "../../config/severity";

const SingleUserTicketsList = () => {
  let content;
  let userName;

  const { id } = useParams();

  const { user } = useGetUsersQuery("usersList", {
    selectFromResult: ({ data }) => ({
      user: data?.entities[id].username,
    }),
  });

  userName = user;

  const {
    data: tickets,
    isLoading,
    isSuccess,
    isError,
    error,
  } = useGetTicketsQuery("ticketsList", {
    pollingInterval: 15000,
    refetchOnFocus: true,
    refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true,
  });

  if (isLoading) content = <PulseLoader color={"#FFF"} />;

  if (isError) content = <p className="errmsg">{error?.data?.message}</p>;

  if (isSuccess) {
    const { ids, entities } = tickets;

    let ticketsIds = [...ids];

    const tableContent = ticketsIds.map((tickets) =>
      entities[tickets].userId === Number(id) ||
      entities[tickets].author === userName ? (
        <tr
          key={entities[tickets].id}
          className="table__row
        "
        >
          <td className="table__cell">
            <Link to={`/dash/tickets/${entities[tickets].id}`}>
              {entities[tickets].name}
            </Link>
          </td>
          <td className="table__cell">{entities[tickets].application}</td>
          <td className="table__cell ticket__status">
            {entities[tickets].status ? (
              <span className="ticket__status--completed">Closed</span>
            ) : (
              <span className="ticket__status--open">Open</span>
            )}
          </td>
          <td className="table__cell ticket__priority">
            {priorityName(entities[tickets].priority)}
          </td>
          <td className="table__cell ticket__severity">
            {severityName(entities[tickets].severity)}
          </td>
          <td className="table__cell ticket__nature">
            {entities[tickets].nature}
          </td>
        </tr>
      ) : null
    );

    content = (
      <table className="table__userbugs">
        <thead className="table__thead">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" className="table__th">
              {userName}'s Bugs
            </th>
            <th scope="col" className="table__th ticket__app">
              App
            </th>
            <th scope="col" className="table__th ticket__status">
              Status
            </th>
            <th scope="col" className="table__th ticket__priority">
              Priority
            </th>
            <th scope="col" className="table__th ticket__severity">
              Severity
            </th>
            <th scope="col" className="table__th ticket__nature">
              Nature
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{tableContent}</tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }

  return content;
};

export default SingleUserTicketsList;
```

Which is housed in this feature: **UsersListing.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
// import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faBug } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { useGetUsersQuery } from "./usersApiSlice";
import PulseLoader from "react-spinners/PulseLoader";

const UsersListing = () => {
  const {
    data: users,
    isLoading,
    isSuccess,
    isError,
    error,
  } = useGetUsersQuery("usersList", {
    pollingInterval: 60000,
    refetchOnFocus: true,
    refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true,
  });

  let content;

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  if (isLoading) content = <PulseLoader color={"#FFF"} />;

  if (isError) {
    content = <p className="errmsg">{error?.data?.message}</p>;
  }

  if (isSuccess) {
    const { ids, entities } = users;

    const tableContent =
      ids?.length &&
      ids.map((id) => (
        <tr key={id} className="table__row">
          <td className="table__cell">
            {/* <Link to={`/dash/user/${id}`} singleUser={entities[id]}> */}
            {entities[id].name + " " + entities[id].surname}
            {/* </Link> */}
          </td>
          <td className="table__cell">{entities[id].role}</td>
          <td className="table__cell">
            <button
              className="icon-button table__button"
              onClick={() => navigate(`/dash/user/${id}`)}
            >
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBug} />
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      ));

    content = (
      <table className="table__userlisting">
        <thead className="table__thead">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" className="table__th user__username">
              Users
            </th>
            <th scope="col" className="table__th user__roles">
              Role
            </th>
            <th scope="col" className="table__th user__tickets">
              Bugs
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{tableContent}</tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }

  return content;
};
export default UsersListing;
```

- Currently trying **useMemo** to sort the **useGetTicketsQuery**

All suggestions, questions, comments are welcomed.